# Deep Linking Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, deep-linking

I am looking for a plugin/ example/ tutorial that would show me how to deep link jquery tabs and nested tabs. Does anyone know where I could find an example of this? I want to do add this to a site, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

The Asual jquery address plugin should sort that out for you, lots of examples as well http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ or on github https://github.com/asual/jquery-address

Or you could try ben alman's jquery bbq plugin

Hope that helps!

Comment: ...actually i'm leaning more to [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) now, requires a little more thought / skill but much better than my previous suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

All solutions using the 'select' method don't work for the later versions of jquery tabs.
It is now done by setting the option active to the desired int (offset is 0) of the tab.
And this function is more leightweight (allas less full featured) than jQuery adress plugin.

```
function initTabs() {
var tabIndex = {'yourTabID-1':0,'yourTabID-2':1,'yourTabID-3':2}
var re = /#\w+$/; // This will match the anchor tag in the URL i.e. http://here.com/page#anchor
var match = re.exec(document.location.toString());
match = location.hash;
if (match != null) var anchor = match.substr(1);
for (key in tabIndex) {
    if (anchor == key) {
        selectedTab = tabIndex[key];
        break;
    }
else selectedTab = 0;
}
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", selectedTab );
//following part only if You need copyable deeplinks

$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {

    var re = /#\w+$/;
    var url = document.location.toString();
var newHash = 'yourTabID-' + ui.newTab.context.id.substring(6);
window.location.hash = newHash;
} );
}
```